# Arrange Array values from a matching pattern in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

Can any one help me in changing array order based on specific value i.e, if my Array=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6] and i want to rearrange the array value if a have some value like 5 then array should be like in the order [5,6,0,1,2,3,4] and if i have a value of 4 then array should start from [4,5,6,0,1,2,3].

```
string[] GetDays; //"Here i will get value from User"
string value; //"This value will also come from User but will always be present in above Array"

if(GetDays.Find(value))
{
    //Rearrange the sort starting with value in ascending
}
```

Note: Array elements are not constant, so we have to programtically arrange the order as some time array can be [1,3,5,6] and if i have value as 5 then my array should change like [5,6,1,3].
Thanks

Comment: What is that code about? Seems totally unrelated.

Comment: The algorithm for this is quite simple, but please show what you have actually tried and what is not working. Stackoverflow is not "please code this for me site".

Comment: `arr = arr.Skip(index).Take(arr.Length - index).Concat(arr.Take(index)).ToArray();`

Comment: Do you have performance / memory requirements that forces you to sort the array inline? Or could you just use Linq instead (like Skip(index).Union(Take(index))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This achieves it in a few lines:

```
int[] test = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
var userValue = 3;
var sorted = test.GroupBy(i => i < userValue).OrderBy(i => i.Key)
            .Select(i => i.OrderBy(j => j)).SelectMany(i => i).ToArray();
```

Output:

```
{3,4,5,6,0,1,2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.Sort with a Comparer: like this:

```
     var a=new []{1,2,3,4,5,6};
     var v=5;
     //Create IComparer
     Comparison<int> comparison = (x,y) => (x >= v && y < v) 
                                ? -1             // Case x is over user value but y is not: x ordered before y
                                : x.CompareTo(y); // otherwise standard comparison;
     Array.Sort(a, comparison);
```

Comment: You might want to add an explanation to that code.

Comment: Thanks: i got it shorter, may be clearer: do the comments help?

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] GetDays = {"s","t","a","c","k"};
string [] temparray = new string[GetDays.Length];
string value = "c";
int index = Array.IndexOf<string>(GetDays, value);
for(int i=0;i<GetDays.Length;i++)
{
    temparray[i] = GetDays[inde];
    index = index+1>=GetDays.Length?0:index+1;          
}
```

And `temparray` will contain the desired output.